# Gradle Exec task shows password

Tags: gradle

How can I get a gradle project.exec or Exec task to not display all information about the commandline?

***code***

```
        project.exec {
            workingDir = exeDir.absolutePath
            executable = starter.absolutePath
            args = commandLine.split().toList()
            environment << envVars
            project.logging.captureStandardOutput LogLevel.INFO
            standardOutput = outputStream
            errorOutput = outputStream
        }
```

***output***

```
Starting process 'command 'regexIdentifier''. Working directory:
/home/code/ Command: /home/code/bin/regexIdentifier server username 
password ...
Successfully started process 'command '/home/code/bin/regexIdentifier''
```

I need to execute a cmd with a password via gradle Exec task and want gradle to not display commandline upon execution

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the gradle Exec task from printing output by default by overriding the standardOutput and errorOutput streams

```
standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
errorOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
```

However, this doesn't prevent the command from showing up when you run with the --info flag.